# Node cannot be found in the current page after Angular HTTP request for dynamically filling a subtable within a table row

Tags: javascript, html, angular, http, asynchronous

My project is meant to load a table of processes and subprocesses of each process. To achieve that, with expandable subprocesses rows, I have thought of the following: the even indexed rows are processes and the odd indexed rows are table rows that hold another table within, with the subprocesses of the processes above corresponding to them.

The problem is that I implemented a pop-up that should open up when a checkbox on the subprocess row of the subprocesses subtable is clicked.

Via local data, it works perfectly, but via HTTP it says "Node cannot be found in the current page." when I select it with the Inspect command in Dev Tools. Further more, it knows that I have HTML but I can't make use of it even after having checked that first the processes are loaded, and then the subprocesses of that processes (which I made sure that are loaded only once, at the first expansion of the hidden row) are loaded, using sessionStorage to retrieve them easily both for the DOM and for the component also.

The toggledIndex variable is the indexed to be opened received via router-outlet from another component. The ng-container *ngIf checks for this index are meant for the checking of whether an HTTP call has been made for that row in particular or not, the toggledIndex being the first upon component initialization and thus a particular case.

processes-menu.component.html:

```
<div id="content">
    <ng-container *ngIf="processesLoaded | async">
        <table>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let process of processes; let i=index">
                <tr style="cursor: pointer">
                    <td class="processName"  (click)="toggleExpanded($event,i)">
                        <i [ngClass]="i===toggledIndex ? 'fa fa-chevron-down' : 'fa fa-chevron-right'"></i>
                        <p>{{process.name}}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="processCheckbox">
                            <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                    <td 
                        [ngClass]="i===toggledIndex ? 'procHead black' : 'procHead white'"
                        (click)="toggleExpanded($event,i)">
                            Description of the requirement
                    </td>
                    <td 
                        [ngClass]="i===toggledIndex ? 'procHead black' : 'procHead white'"
                        (click)="toggleExpanded($event,i)">
                            Overall intent of the requirement
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <ng-container *ngIf="i===toggledIndex">
                    <tr style="width: 100%; height: fit-content;">
                        <td colspan="4" style="height: fit-content; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
                            <table class="subprocessesTable">
                                <ng-container *ngIf="get(i)">
                                    <ng-container *ngFor="let subprocess of get(i).subprocesses; let j=index">
                                        <tr class="subprocessRow">
                                            <td class="subprocessName">{{subprocess.name}}</td>
                                            <td class="subprocessState">
                                                <div 
                                                    style="pointer-events: auto; cursor: pointer;"
                                                    (click)="toggleLevelPopup($event)">
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                </div>
                                            </td>

                                            <td class="pop-up">
                                                <!-- <level-pop-up style="display: none;"></level-pop-up> -->
                                                <level-pop-up></level-pop-up>
                                            </td>

                                            <td class="descReq">

                                                <ng-container *ngIf="subprocess.descriptionReq.length>160">
                                                    <div 
                                                        style="cursor: pointer"
                                                        onclick="if(this.nextSibling.style.visibility==='hidden') this.nextSibling.style.visibility=''">
                                                            {{trim(subprocess.descriptionReq)}}
                                                    </div>                                                        
                                                    <text-pop-up style="visibility: hidden;" [popText]="subprocess.descriptionReq"></text-pop-up>
                                                </ng-container>

                                                <ng-container *ngIf="subprocess.descriptionReq.length<=160">
                                                    {{subprocess.descriptionReq}}
                                                </ng-container>

                                            </td>

                                            <td class="intentReq">

                                                <ng-container *ngIf="subprocess.intentReq.length>160">
                                                    <div 
                                                        style="pointer-events: auto; cursor: pointer"
                                                        onclick="if(this.nextSibling.style.visibility==='hidden') this.nextSibling.style.visibility=''">
                                                            {{trim(subprocess.intentReq)}}
                                                    </div>                                                        
                                                    <text-pop-up style="visibility: hidden;" [popText]="subprocess.intentReq"></text-pop-up>
                                                </ng-container>

                                                <ng-container *ngIf="subprocess.intentReq.length<=160">
                                                    {{subprocess.intentReq}}
                                                </ng-container>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </ng-container>      
                                </ng-container>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container *ngIf="i!==toggledIndex">
                    <tr style="display: none; height: 0; width: 100%">
                        <td colspan="4" style="height: fit-content; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;">
                            <table class="subprocessesTable">
                                <ng-container *ngIf="get(i)">
                                    <ng-container *ngFor="let subprocess of get(i).subprocesses; let j=index">
                                        <tr class="subprocessRow">
                                            <td class="subprocessName">{{subprocess.name}}</td>
                                            <td class="subprocessState">
                                                <div 
                                                    style="cursor: pointer;"
                                                    (click)="toggleLevelPopup($event)">
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                </div>
                                            </td>

                                            <td class="pop-up">
                                                <!-- <level-pop-up style="display: none;"></level-pop-up> -->
                                                <level-pop-up></level-pop-up>                                                
                                            </td>

                                            <td class="descReq">
                                                <ng-container *ngIf="subprocess.descriptionReq.length>160">
                                                    <div 
                                                        style="cursor: pointer"
                                                        onclick="if(this.nextSibling.style.visibility==='hidden') this.nextSibling.style.visibility=''">
                                                            {{trim(subprocess.descriptionReq)}}
                                                    </div>                                                        
                                                    <text-pop-up style="visibility: hidden;" [popText]="subprocess.descriptionReq"></text-pop-up>
                                                </ng-container>
                                                <ng-container *ngIf="subprocess.descriptionReq.length<=160">
                                                    {{subprocess.descriptionReq}}
                                                </ng-container>
                                            </td>

                                            <td class="intentReq">

                                                <ng-container *ngIf="subprocess.intentReq.length>160">
                                                    <div 
                                                        style="cursor: pointer"
                                                        onclick="if(this.nextSibling.style.visibility==='hidden') this.nextSibling.style.visibility=''">
                                                            {{trim(subprocess.intentReq)}}
                                                    </div>                                                        
                                                    <text-pop-up style="visibility: hidden;" [popText]="subprocess.intentReq"></text-pop-up>
                                                </ng-container>

                                                <ng-container *ngIf="subprocess.intentReq.length<=160">
                                                    {{subprocess.intentReq}}
                                                </ng-container>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </ng-container>      
                                </ng-container>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </table>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

processes-menu.component.ts:

```
  httpSubscription1: any;
  httpSubscription2: any;
  httpSubscription3: any;
  processes: any = [];
  subprocessesOfProcess: any = [];
  toggledIndex: any;
  processesLoaded: Promise<boolean>;

  constructor(
    private globalData: DataBetweenUnrelatedService, 
    private httpService: HttpRetrieveService, 
    private router: Router, 
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe (params => this.toggledIndex = parseInt(params["toggledIndex"]));

    console.log('INIT MENU', this.toggledIndex);

    this.httpSubscription1 = this.httpService.getData(myGlobals.URL+'/processes/allProcesses').subscribe(data => {
      this.processes = data;
      this.globalData.processExpansionState = [];
      this.globalData.subprocessesCalled = [];
      this.subprocessesOfProcess = [];
      for(let i=0; i<this.processes.length; i++){
        this.globalData.processExpansionState.push(i===this.toggledIndex ? true : false);
        this.globalData.subprocessesCalled.push(i===this.toggledIndex ? true : false);
        this.subprocessesOfProcess.push({});
      }
      this.processesLoaded = Promise.resolve(true);
    });
    
    this.httpSubscription2 = this.httpService.getData(myGlobals.URL+`/subprocesses/allSubprocessesOfAProcess?processId=${this.toggledIndex+1}`).subscribe( data => {
        this.subprocessesOfProcess[this.toggledIndex] = {
          processIndex: this.toggledIndex,
          subprocesses: data
        };
        this.save(this.toggledIndex, JSON.stringify(this.subprocessesOfProcess[this.toggledIndex]));
      });

  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    if(this.httpSubscription1) this.httpSubscription1.unsubscribe();
    if(this.httpSubscription2) this.httpSubscription2.unsubscribe();
    if(this.httpSubscription3) this.httpSubscription3.unsubscribe();
    console.log('DESTROY MENU');
  }

  save(key, value){
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }

  get(key){
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
  }

  switchToOverview(event){
    this.router.navigate(['/','dashboard']);
  }

  trim(string){
    return string.slice(0, 160)+'...';
  }

  toggleLevelPopup(event){
    console.log(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.firstChild);
    // HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO SHOW OR HIDE MY CUSTOM POP-UP COMPONENT WHEN I CLICK 
    // ON THE ROW CHECKBOX
    // BUT THE PROBLEM IS THAT I CAN'T MAKE USE OF THE DYMANICALLY ADDED HTML, WHICH
    // ALSO IMPACTS THE POINTER EVENTS THAT I HAD MADE WITHIN THE POP-UP COMPONENT
    // (RENDERS IT USELESS BASICALLY)
  }

  toggleExpanded(event, i){
    let clickedRow: any;
    let expandedRow: any;
    let icon: any;
    let description1: any;
    let description2: any;
    
    if(i===this.toggledIndex){
      clickedRow = event.target.parentElement;
      expandedRow = event.target.parentElement.nextSibling;
      this.globalData.subprocessesCalled[i]=true;
    }else{
      clickedRow = event.target.parentElement;
      expandedRow = event.target.parentElement.nextSibling.nextSibling;
    }

    this.globalData.processExpansionState[i] = !this.globalData.processExpansionState[i];

    switch(this.globalData.processExpansionState[i]){
      case true:
        if(!this.globalData.subprocessesCalled[i]){
          this.httpSubscription3 = this.httpService.getData(myGlobals.URL+`/subprocesses/allSubprocessesOfAProcess?processId=${i+1}`).subscribe( data => {
            this.subprocessesOfProcess[i] = {
              processIndex: i,
              subprocesses: data
            };

            this.globalData.subprocessesCalled[i] = !this.globalData.subprocessesCalled[i];

            this.save(i, JSON.stringify(this.subprocessesOfProcess[i]));
          });
        }
        
        icon = clickedRow.children[0].children[0];
        icon.classList.remove('fa-chevron-right');
        icon.classList.add('fa-chevron-down');

        description1 = clickedRow.children[2];
        description2 = clickedRow.children[3];

        description1.classList.add('black');
        description1.classList.remove('white');
        description2.classList.add('black');
        description2.classList.remove('white');

        expandedRow.style.display = '';
        expandedRow.style.height = 'fit-content';

        break;

      case false:
        icon = clickedRow.children[0].children[0];
        icon.classList.remove('fa-chevron-down');
        icon.classList.add('fa-chevron-right');

        description1 = clickedRow.children[2];
        description2 = clickedRow.children[3];

        description1.classList.add('white');
        description1.classList.remove('black');
        description2.classList.add('white');
        description2.classList.remove('black');
        
        expandedRow.style.display = 'none';
        expandedRow.style.height = '0';
        break;
    }
  }
```